# Size limitation on char Array on ESP8266

Tags: array

I'm creating a log of events, stored as a txt file. If it matters, I'm using ESP8266.

To display the log of each IOT, I'm publishing the txt file to a disgnated MQTT topic for all my IOT devices (later on to Telegram ). For sorting ( new first and old last ) I read each line into char array, post it to MQTT, and save it back to txt file.

Currently char array is defined as: `char log_array[20][200]` - meaning I'm keeping a log of 20 records, of 200 chars long.

Is it the right way ( declare a char array ) ? are there any limitation for size of array ( say 200 records )

Guy

Comment: That method looks fine to me. Are you having a specific problem with it, or are you just sanity checking?

Comment: @Majenko both. Since I do not initiate the char array, but only define it I'm worry that define it to 200 entries ( or more ) will cause sporadic crashes, ones which I will not be able to track

Comment: If you initialize it as a global then it will go in the BSS. That gets initialized to 0, so your array will be filled with 0. Since 0 is the "End Of String" marker you just end up with 20 empty strings of length 0.  If it's a local variable it'll be on the stack, and then will be filled with who knows what. In that case initializing it to 0 with `memset(log_array, 0, 20*200);` will do the same job.

Comment: @Majenko it will be defined as part of my `iot` library - an instance which is defined globally ( does it mean' defined globally ? )

Comment: In that case it should be in the BSS in which case it should be all 0. You can force that by adding the memset into the constructor of your class (I assume you're using a class?).

Comment: @Majenko yes, it is a class

Comment: Then I can't see a problem. You're using <4kB on a chip with 80kB of RAM (though not contiguous blocks), which is nothing really.